# Broken Dependencies (Symbol Lookup Error for hb_font_funcs_set_variation_glyph_func in libpangoft2-1.0.so.0) from 16.04 to 18.04

Tags: do-release-upgrade

I have been upgrading my OS in stages to get to a current LTS version.  Yesterday I ran 'do-release-upgrade' after running 'sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade; sudo apt-get dist-upgrade' per recommendations in posts here.  Post-upgrade, a number of broken dependencies appeared.

Now, *synaptic*, *apt-get*, and *software-properties-gtk* and many other important programs won't run, producing this error:

> synaptic: symbol lookup error:
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangoft2-1.0.so.0: undefined symbol:
> hb_font_funcs_set_variation_glyph_func

Commands like `apt --fix-broken install` or `sudo apt-get install -f`, and the other usual recommendations have not corrected the issue.  Are there different strategies to try?

---

```
$ which synaptic
/usr/sbin/synaptic

$ dpkg -S $(which synaptic)
synaptic: /usr/bin/synaptic

$ ldd $(which synaptic) | grep local
# produces no result. 

$ dpkg -S /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangoft2-1.0.so.0
libpangoft2-1.0-0:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangoft2-1.0.so.0
$ apt-cache policy synaptic libpangoft2-1.0-0
synaptic:
  Installed: 0.83
  Candidate: 0.84.3ubuntu1
  Version table:
     0.84.3ubuntu1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
 *** 0.83 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libpangoft2-1.0-0:
  Installed: 1.40.14-1ubuntu0.1
  Candidate: 1.40.14-1ubuntu0.1
  Version table:
 *** 1.40.14-1ubuntu0.1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.40.14-1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
spowell@raven:/etc/apt$ apt-cache policy synaptic libpangoft2-1.0-0
synaptic:
  Installed: 0.83
  Candidate: 0.84.3ubuntu1
  Version table:
     0.84.3ubuntu1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
 *** 0.83 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libpangoft2-1.0-0:
  Installed: 1.40.14-1ubuntu0.1
  Candidate: 1.40.14-1ubuntu0.1
  Version table:
 *** 1.40.14-1ubuntu0.1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.40.14-1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages

The output of 'dpkg -l | grep ^ii -v' is available at pastebin https://pastebin.com/HhJu3mZu

The output of 'sudo aptitude safe-upgrade' is:

> The following packages will be REMOVED:  
  groff-base{u} libgdbm5{u} libpipeline1{u} man-db{u} 
The following partially installed packages will be configured:
  bsdmainutils libbsd0 liblocale-gettext-perl libsmartcols1 libtinfo5 libuuid1 
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 4 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 6,017 kB will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n/?] Y
dpkg: error: duplicate file trigger interest for filename '/usr/lib/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders' and package 'libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:i386'
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
dpkg: error: duplicate file trigger interest for filename '/usr/lib/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders' and package 'libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:i386'
```

Comment: Please show the output of the following commands to the question: `which synaptic`, `dpkg -S $(which synaptic)`, `ldd $(which synaptic) | grep local`, `dpkg -S /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangoft2-1.0.so.0` , `apt-cache policy synaptic libpangoft2-1.0-0` .

Comment: Have you tried to use Aptitude? Something like `sudo apt install aptitude`, `sudo aptitude dist-upgrade` to get newest dependencies.

Comment: 'which synaptic':

Comment: Add all outputs to the question by editing it.

Comment: 'which synaptic': yields /usr/sbin/synaptic.  'dpkg -S $(which synaptic)' yields synaptic: /usr/bin/synaptic.  'ldd $(which synaptic) | grep local' produces no result. 'dpkg -S /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangoft2-1.0.so.0' produces 'libpangoft2-1.0-0:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangoft2-1.0.so.0'. 'apt-cache policy synaptic libpangoft2-1.0-0' produces 'synaptic:
  Installed: 0.83
  Candidate: 0.84.3ubuntu1
  Version table:
     0.84.3ubuntu1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64
libpangoft2-1.0-0:
  Installed: 1.40.14-1ubuntu0.1

Comment: I ran Aptitude several times and it failed despite repeatedly telling it to work harder.  The usual tools haven't solved the situation, unfortunately.

Comment: Please add output of `dpkg -l | grep ^ii -v` along with `aptitude search ~o` to the question (or upload to pastebin if long).

Comment: output of 'dpkg -l | grep ^ii -v added to pastebin: https://pastebin.com/HhJu3mZu

Comment: Try `sudo aptitude safe-upgrade` .

Comment: 'sudo aptitude safe-upgrade' output is included in the original post...  "duplicate file trigger interest" error has been showing up a lot as I've been running the various corrective attempts.  another error that has been popping up a lot while trying to launch programs like thunderbird is "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangoft2-1.0.so.0: undefined symbol: hb_font_funcs_set_variation_glyph_func".  Trying to reinstall that library produces the "duplicate file trigger" error.

Comment: Then you have to edit `/var/lib/dpkg/triggers/File` and remove one of the `/usr/lib/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders` lines. Then retry.

Comment: Thanks.  Had to remove several duplicate lines in /var/lib/dpkg/triggers/File manually (the sed command others used successfully to remove duplicates did not work for me), but finally got 'sudo aptitude safe-upgrade' to finish.  The original error message "symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangoft2-1.0.so.0: undefined symbol: hb_font_funcs_set_variation_glyph_func" remained, but once dpkg wanted to work again after removing duplicate triggers I was able to reinstall the offending library with 'sudo apt-get install --reinstall libpangoft2-1.0."  Thanks for the help!

Comment: @N0rbert It seems I can't mark your answer "accepted" since they're in the comments, but this issue can be called resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution of the problem was multi-step:

1. Install all upgrades without package removal by

   ```
   sudo aptitude safe-upgrade
   ```
2. Remove duplicate trigger `/usr/lib/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders` from `/var/lib/dpkg/triggers/File`

To get all upgrades installed I would recommend to run

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```